# FirebaseException: Invalid Firebase path. paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '['

Tags: android, firebase, exception, firebase-realtime-database, chat

i want to create chat app by using firebase database for that i'm using [this example](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/firebase/real-time-android-chat-application-using-firebase-tutorial/) but when i open chat screen by selecting user,

it throws follwoing error:

```
com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Invalid Firebase path: /messages/abc_def.com. Firebase paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
```

exception in line..

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
            reference1 = new Firebase("https://yourproject.firebaseio.com/messages/" + com.firebase.chat.UserDetails.username + "_" + UserDetails.chatWith);
            reference2 = new Firebase("https://yourproject.firebaseio.com/messages/" + UserDetails.chatWith + "_" + UserDetails.username);
```

one day before it was working fine but now its throwing this error. can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URLEncoder.encode(message,"UTF-8");` for encoding(writing) the message and `URLDecoder.decode(message,"UTF-8");` for decoding (reading)

Comment: com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Invalid Firebase url specified


String message = "https://arraylist-7a383.firebaseio.com/messages/" + com.firebase.chat.UserDetails.username + "_" + UserDetails.chatWith;
            reference1 = new Firebase(URLEncoder.encode(message,"UTF-8"));

Comment: please log the url